# Which statistical test should I apply to my case which consists of categorical and continuous variables?

Tags: categorical-data, continuous-data

I have got the following data:
I have the amount of walking of the person in **min** as the dependent variable **(continuous)** and I have got a **mix of categorical and continuous** variables as independent variables (however mostly categorical variables) (e.g. age (continuous),gender, scorehealth, educationcategorie, incomecategorie, level of the work, rating giving in terms of safeness and pleasantness of the neighborhood, having or not having a dog and the distance to green (continuous) . I was wondering what type of statistal test I should apply to my case

My purpose is to use the output of the statistical test in my simulationmodel to simulate walking behavior, so if someone for example is female with certain characteristics, she will walk for ..... minutes, something like that.

Comment: You can't apply a statistical test to a research in general, however you can apply it to a question. I suggest you that instead of asking about techniques (like statistical test) you better describe which are the questions you want to ask. For some of them, maybe, you could answer with a statistical test, but for others maybe not.

Comment: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5338/1352

Comment: my main research question is "What is the effect of green on the walking behavior in elderly?" however I for now I would like to see from the varialbes the importance or the weight they contribute to walking in min. So I would like to know the importance of these variables and use these weights afterwards for my simulation model. Maybe I should have elaborated that in my text above.

Comment: I guess that "green" here means distance to the nearest green space. The general territory here is regression, but you need to watch out. Are there zeros in the outcome or response (a much better term than _dependent variable_), so that some people didn't do any walking? My first recommendation is Poisson regression here and don't be put off by a myth that the response must be discrete. See e.g. https://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/ More generally, a generalized linear model sounds a good idea.

Comment: @NickCox Wow thanks for the information. Indeed with green, I meant the distance to green and indeed as you have guessed there were people who didn't walk at all. I never heard of the Poisson distribution, but I will look it up and come back later.

Comment: It's Poisson regression you need to focus on, not so much Poisson distribution.

Comment: @NickCox, sorry I would like to upvote your comments, however I don't have enough reputation points :( . Still, I hoped you would like to answer my question. I managed to do the poisson regression in rstudio based on the following website https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/poisson-regression/  I did a goodness of fit test for the overall model and I got quite bad results:  the website mentions possible reasons:  there might be omitted predictor variables, the linearity assumption may not hold  and/or if there is an issue of over-dispersion. However I have no idea ho to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation. To get further advice you really have to show more about your data and your results so far. Your question is on all fours with "my results are disappointing; what do I do next?" except that you have specific suggestions to act on.

Comment: @NickCox, I might be able to show the results of my model, however in terms of the data I have signed a paper that I am not to  ought to share the data with third parties, so sorry I am not able to do that. :( I know by doing that, it is difficult to get specific feedback, since I it's very difficult to guess what might be going on with the data or Rstudio.

Comment: Understood, but that rules out most fruitful discussion. All I can say is that for your kind of data a lot of unexplained variation is expected and not surprising. You can know my age (enormous) and gender (a fairly common one) and education level (tremendous) and income (not enough) and some other stuff, and similarly for other people, and you've barely begun to specify all possible predictors of walking time.